# anomaly in a Latin hexameter

Tags: latin, poetry

I read in Ovid, Metamorphoses , 1.502-503 :

> ```
>                                  fugit ōcior aurā 
> illa leuī nequ(e) ad haec reuocantis uerba resistit.
> ```

My (rough) translation :

> ```
>    But she flees, quicker than the soft breeze,
> and resists these words calling her back again.
> ```

I'm stuck with the scansion of the verse 503 :

> ```
> illa leuī nequ(e) ad haec reuocantis uerba resistit.
> 1  -2-  3  4          5   -6-  7 8   9   -10- 11 12
> ```

With the "ad" word this verse seems to have 13 syllables, not 12. There at least [one person](https://sites.google.com/site/apolloetdaphne/courses/lines-502-507) thinking that this "ad" should be elided but this correction seems very curious.

I don't have any critic edition of the Metamorphoses. Is the text questionable ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The verse is correct. ne-qu(e)a-d(h)aec is three sylables: short + short + long.

Comment: You're right, of course. I completely forgot that "ne" before "qu" could be short.